# How to DIsable Button When DataGridView Data Source is empty? C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have `DataGridView` with a empty `DataTable` as `DataSource`. When the main form loads it will show an empty `DataGridView` so user can entry data on it. I want to disable the `Save Data` menu when `DataGridView`is empty. I tried this code :

```
private void dGV_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt = dGV.DataSource as DataTable;
            int d = dt.Columns.Count + 1;
            foreach (var column in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray())
            {
                if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(column)))
                    d--;
            }
            if (d > 0)
            {
                saveDataToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            }
            else {
                saveDataToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
```

The `Save Data` menu will be disabled when form loads

[image]

and it will be enabled when I entry a value on the `dGV`. 
[image]

But the `Save Data` menu wont be disabled when I delete that value and the `dGV` becomes empty again.

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why not you check for rows count on form load, and disable the menu button if it i zero. And when you make any entry at that time you can enable the menu item

Comment: @MuhammadIdrees yes but I want the menu disabled again when I empty the dGV

Comment: How the dGV get empty "again". Do you have any delete functionality also. If so then call the same code on that event also, to make the menu item enabled/disabled

Comment: Then put the call to disable in the code that does empty the grid

Comment: I assume that the button which you're trying to disable is a "remove" button, to remove data from the form. If that's the case, just add a check at the end of the buttons click event to hide or disable the button if the DataGridView is now empty... Similarly, you should check on startup and in any other button event which may remove contents from the view.

Comment: @MuhammadIdrees I added the screenshots

Comment: Buddy, if you are using ADO.NET you should check `DataTable.GetChanges()` for this. It will tell you is there any pending changes. You should just check changes on menu appearing event, and disable menu item if there is not modified rows

Answer (score 0):

1- When the form loads, check If dGV is empty, then set the menu button disabled.

2- When creating a new entry, make button enabled.

3- When Remove button is clicked. Check if dGV is empty or have records, then again disable the menuitem if it is empty.

Comment: thank you! but i dont have remove button.. i empty the cell by simpy edit it and press backspace..

Comment: At the moment you press backspace, you delete some transaction in database, just right after that, check if you have no more records then disable the button